# How to get Angular to only redraw elements of a CSS grid when their corresponding array element has changed

Tags: arrays, angular, css-grid, conways-game-of-life, angular-changedetection

I've implemented Conway's Game of Life in Angular using CSS grid. I've noticed that even with a relatively small grid (50 squares x 50 squares) there is a discernible visual lag between clicking on the button for the next tick and the update of the grid.

I suspected that Angular was redrawing all of the squares every tick, even though only a small percentage of them actually change. I added some fading animation that confirmed my suspicion. Actually, not entirely. Sometimes, certain cells aren't redrawn but it almost seems random. Most cells are inactive (white) and so do not need to be redrawn. Yet most of them are, but not all. Sometimes a few rows won't be redrawn and the rest will.

I've tried adding a trackBy function to track by index. That didn't seem to help.

Here is a link to the project on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conway?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Here is the code:

```html
<div
  style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(50, 15px); grid-template-rows: repeat(50, 15px)"
>
  <div
    *ngFor="let alive of grid; index as i"
    class="my-animation"
    [ngStyle]="{'border': 'solid black 1px', 'background-color':  alive ? 'black' : 'white'}"
  ></div>
</div>

<button (click)="nextTick()">Next</button>
```

```js
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { getNeighbors } from "../../get-neighbors";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  grid: boolean[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._randomStart(0.1);
  }

  private _randomStart(probabilityOfAlive: number): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {
      this.grid[i] = Math.random() <= probabilityOfAlive;
    }
  }

  nextTick(): void {
    this._updateGrid();
  }

  private _updateGrid(): void {
    const newGrid = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {
      const isAlive = this.grid[i];
      const liveNeighborsCount = this._getLiveNeighborsCount(i);
      if (isAlive && (liveNeighborsCount === 2 || liveNeighborsCount === 3))
        newGrid[i] = true;
      else if (!isAlive && liveNeighborsCount === 3) newGrid[i] = true;
      else newGrid[i] = false;
    }

    this.grid = newGrid;
  }

  private _getLiveNeighborsCount(cellIndex: number): number {
    return getNeighbors({ index: cellIndex, width: 50, heigth: 50 }).reduce(
      (sumOfAlive, indexOfNeighbor) => {
        return this.grid[indexOfNeighbor] ? sumOfAlive + 1 : sumOfAlive;
      },
      0
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what code you used for trackBy. Because likely that will solve your problem but it may not be implemented correctly.

Comment: @MindingData your instincts were correct. I had inverted the index and item params in the function signature. Once fixed, it behaved as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the only thing wrong with my original implementation was the trackBy function. I had inverted the params order and thus was tracking by value instead of by index. Once I implemented the function properly everything worked as expected without having to make any other changes.

```
trackByIndex(index: number): number {
  return index;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right. There is a lag because Angular redraw all the grid cells each tick. This is because you ask it to do so in your template: each time the `grid` array changes the DOM cells are redrawn (which take time) because the `ngFor` loop execute.

To avoid full redraw of the grid consider drawing the grid only once and simply updating CSS style of the cells each tick.

To achieve this,

1. in your component, add a dummy static array with 2500 empty elements that will be used by the `ngFor` loop to draw the grid only once:

```
cells = Array(2500);
```

2. change your template this way:

```
<div *ngFor="let cell of cells; index as i"
     class="my-animation"
     [ngStyle]="{'border': 'solid black 1px', 'background-color':  grid[i] ? 'black' : 'white'}">
</div>
```

See it in action here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conway-h8wvfj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it like below

1. Create a new component grid-item-component with html

```html
  <div
    class="my-animation"
    [ngStyle]="{'border': 'solid black 1px', 'background-color':  isAlive ? 'black' : 'white'}"
  >
  &nbsp;
  </div>
```

and TS

```typescript
  import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input,  OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class GridItemComponent {
  @Input('is-alive') isAlive
}
```

The idea is that whenever the input isAlive changes, then this component will be updated otherwise it will not since we are using the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

2. Change the html, dont forget to include the `trackBy` function. We will track by index using `trackByIndex` function

```html
<button (click)="nextTick()">Next</button>
<div
  style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(50, 15px); grid-template-rows: repeat(50, 15px)"
>
  <app-grid-item
    *ngFor="let alive of grid; index as i; trackBy:trackByIndex"
    [is-alive]='alive'   
  ></app-grid-item>
</div>
```

3. In your TS file add below function

```typescript
trackByIndex = (i) =>  i
```

below is a [sample demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conway-asztuj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)